# onAuthStateChanged being called too early

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm tyring to create a new user with some additional data (eg: subscribeToEmail field etc.). From what I have read online, the way to go about doing this is to authenticate a user (eg: by using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`), and then using the `uid` that I obtain from that to create a new document in a users collection. That is what I'm trying to do below:

```
const handleSignup = async (formData) => {
  const {email, password, ...otherUserData} = formData;
  const {user} = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,  password);
  console.log("generating user doc at signup...");
  await generateUserDocument(user, otherUserData); // creates user doc (called 2nd)
}
```

The `generateUserDocument` will create a user document (if it doesn't already exist) in the `users` collection using the uid of the `user` obtained from the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function call. I also have also set up an auth state change event handler:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => { // get the current user 
  if (userAuth) {
    const user = await generateUserDocument(userAuth); // user (should) already exists, so generateUserDocument will fetch the user rather than creating a new user doc, but this doesn't happen, as it is called 1st and not 2nd
    dispatch(login(user)); // login logic
  } else {
    dispatch(logout());
  }
});
```

The issue here is, when I call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` the `onAuthStateChanged` callback triggers, which then calls `generateUserDocument` **before** I have actually created a user document with `generateUserDocument(user, otherUserData);` inside of the handleSignup method. In other words, the fetch user method:  `generateUserDocument` inside of `.onAuthStateChange()` is being invoked before the user is actually created, which is done by the `generateUserDocument` inside of the `handleSignup` method. As a result, the user data I'm fetching inside of authStateChange doesn't include the details I'm after.

Is there a way to fix this so that my function call after the `auth.createuserWithEmailAndPassword()` is called *before* the onAuthStateChange event handler is executed (rather than after)? I have thaught about using something like `.onSnapshot()` perhaps, but I'm thinking that this might be a little overkill as the user data table shouldn't really need to be continously be listened too, as it will rarely changed. Preferably there is a lifecycle method that gets invoked before `onAuthStateChanged` that I could use to populate my users collection, but I haven't been able to find much on that.

For reference, I have been following [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/user-authentication-firebase-react-apps/) regarding associating additional user data with a auth-user record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to fix this so that my function call after the
> `auth.createuserWithEmailAndPassword()` is called before the
> `onAuthStateChange` event handler is executed (rather than after)?

No, there is no out-of-the-box way, because

1. On successful creation of the user account with `createuserWithEmailAndPassword()` the user **will also be signed in** to your application (see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword)), and
2. The `onAuthStateChange()` observer is triggered **on sign-in** or sign-out.

So you indeed need to wait the user Firestore doc is created before proceeding. In my opinion, the best approach is the one you have mentioned, i.e. setting a listener to the `user` document.

You can do that in such a way you cancel the listener right after the first time you get the data from the user doc, as shown below. This way the user doc **is not continuously being listened to**.

```
  auth.onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {    // No more need to be async
    // get the current user
    if (userAuth) {
      const userDocRef = firestore.collection('users').doc(userAuth.uid);
      const listener = userDocRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log(doc.data());
          // Do any other action you need with the user's doc data

          listener();   // Calling the unsubscribe function that cancels the listener

          dispatch(login(user));
        }
      });
    } else {
      dispatch(logout());
    }
  });
```

---

Another approach could be to use a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) which, in the backend, creates the user in the Auth service AND the document in Firestore. Your `handleSignup` function would be as follows:

```
const handleSignup = async (formData) => {
  const createUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createUser');
  await createUser({formData});
  // The user is created in the Auth service
  // and the user doc is created in Firestore

  // We then need to signin the user, since the call to the Cloud Function did not do it!
  const {email, password, ...otherUserData} = formData;
  await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  // The onAuthStateChanged listener is triggered and the Firestore doc does exist
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, I really like both options that you've presented. I haven't really worked with cloud functions before, but this gives me a good idea about how they might be used, thanks again :)

Comment: Glad I could help you. You may be interested by [this article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which shows how to create user accounts via a Callable Cloud Function.

Comment: Oh great, thank you very much, I'll give it a read. I've been wanting to learn more about cloud functions so this will help with that. Cheers!